# Various attributes in Android Studio not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am running an Android studio application and am getting the following errors:

attributes such as: app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" and other such app:layout attributes in my xml project files are consistently not found by the compiler. In addition, in some of my java files, the resource R is not found. I have tried syncing with gradle files, restarting with cache, etc, and nothing seems to be working. Also note that this is an imported project from another source, and the original unimported project works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe is that you are not running the latest version and the version of the gradle for the new project is higher . That's why you are getting errors.

Use the newer version of updste your gradle

Comment: which version of Android studio you are currently using? ps: I will suggest you to use the latest version or atleast above 3.+.